# Delete text enclosed in square brackets from a string

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have records that include text between square brackets.

```
aaaaaa[aaaaa]
```

I need to erase that text, square brackets included.

The result would be:

```
aaaaaa
```

I'm trying this code:

```
Dim sqr as Integer
Dim origin as String
Dim result as String

InStr(origin,[)
```

I can find the first square bracket, but it does not do the job.

Comment: `result=left(origin, instr(origin & "[", "[") - 1)`  returns all to the left of `[` or the whole string if there is no `[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work out the index of the opening square bracket - `InStr(origin, "[")` (note the double quotes) is a good start.

Now you can loop from that index up to the end of the string, using the `Mid$` function to inspect the character at the current index, until the closing bracket is located:

```
Dim currentPosition As Long
currentPosition = InStr(origin, "[")
If currentPosition = 0 Then
    ' no opening bracket. now what?
Else
    Dim bracketedWord As String
    For currentPosition = currentPosition + 1 To Len(origin)
        If Mid$(origin, currentPosition, 1) <> "]" Then
            bracketedWord = bracketedWord & Mid$(origin, currentPosition, 1)
        Else
            'found the closing bracket: we're done.
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End If
```

Or, you can use `InStr` to locate the `[` opening brace *and* the closing brace `]` positions, then compute the *length* of the substring between these two positions, and use the `Mid$` function to pull the substring without looping.

Alternatively, with a reference to *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5* you could use a simple regular expression:

```
Public Function FindBracketedWord(ByVal value As String) As String
    Dim regex As RegExp
    Set regex = new RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "\[(\w+)\]" ' matches a square-bracketed "word", no spaces

    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Set matches = regex.Execute(value)

    If matches.Count <> 0 Then result = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
    FindBracketedWord = result
End Function
```

Comment: Some good solutions, but your answer seems to be obtaining the text within the square brackets, not removing it from the original content as requested by the OP - I'm unsure why this has been marked as the solution, unless I've missed something.

Comment: @LeeMac well once you know the opening and closing brackets positions, you're done. Apparently OP didn't need to be spoonfed the replacement part, only needed help locating the closing bracket.

Comment: I agree that the opening/closing bracket positions are key to the solution, but given that your solution seemed to be performing the opposite of the question, I thought there may have been some misunderstanding was all.

Answer (score 2):

Since in your question you state that you wish to **remove** text within square brackets (including removing the brackets), I would suggest the following:

```
Function RemoveSqBracketText(strStr As String) As String
    Dim lngId1 As Long
    Dim lngId2 As Long
    lngId1 = InStr(strStr, "[")
    lngId2 = InStr(strStr, "]")
    If lngId1 > 0 And lngId2 > 0 Then
        RemoveSqBracketText = Left(strStr, lngId1 - 1) & RemoveSqBracketText(Mid(strStr, lngId2 + 1))
    Else
        RemoveSqBracketText = strStr
    End If
End Function
```

This will recursively remove all instances of text enclosed in square brackets, and assumes that you only wish to remove text if it is enclosed within an opening **and** closing bracket.

#### Examples:

```
?RemoveSqBracketText("abc[123]")
abc

?RemoveSqBracketText("abc[123]def[ghi]")
abcdef

?RemoveSqBracketText("abc[123]defghi]")
abcdefghi]
```